# Which AWS service to use to create my own SSO service that supports OpenID Connect?

Tags: amazon-web-services

There is a mobile app that uses OpenID Connect for SSO. That mobile app is not built with AWS. Developers of that app are asking me to provide my own SSO service with OpenID Connect that they can use authentication of users in that app.

**My question is:** Which AWS service to use to create my own SSO service that will support OpenID Connect and that will allow app created outside of AWS to use my SSO service for users authentication?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Identify provider, see this documentation :
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_create_oidc.html